# Can I customize the reuse of UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, carousel

I will create a carousel using UICollectionView.
And I want the cells outside the bounds of UICollectionView would be visible.

So I added this code because I thought it's an easy problem.

```
collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
collectionView.clipsToBounds = false
```

But, Of course, some cells outside the bounds were hidden by reuse.

Is there anyway to use UICollectionView without reuse, or to adjust the reuse range, or ...etc?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just make the collection view wider? What are you trying to achieve by not clipping?

Comment: @matt Because I want to use paging built in UICollectionView to pure. That works perfectly and simply if it hasn't the hidden cells issue. If there is no easy way, I have to make the collection view wider.

Comment: That is the usual solution. In fact, the usual solution is to make the collection view wider than the screen. That gives you a nice gap between the pages. Apple recommends that.

Comment: Alternatively if there is something you want to hide, just put a view in front of it, or clip it from a superview.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can in fact use UICollectionView without reuse.

in collectionview's datasource function :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

instead of using

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
```

and returning the cell, you can create your own cell without calling collectionView's dequeue function and return this newly created cell

the downside to this is everytime your collectionview need a new cell, it will creates a new cell and not reusing the one you already had, resulting in overtime increasing memory hogging cells

to solve this, you can arrange an array that keep track of which cell to use on which index, and fetch cell from this array (if its available) or create one when its not and append it to the array